# cur execute repeating parameter

Tags: python, sql, mysql-python

I am performing a SQL query in python. What is the correct way of representing parameters that are repeating?
Example : I have

```
cur.execute("""select * from TableA where field1= '{}' and field2 = '{}'""".format(a,a))
```

Here 'a' and 'a' are the same. Do I need to repeat it in the parameter list or is there some way of just giving it once.

Comment: Which library are you using to do this? MySQLdb?

Comment: Yes i am using mysqldb for this.

Comment: Don't use string interpolation (`.format()`) because of the risk of SQL-injection.  Instead do `cur.execute("select * from TableA where field1= '%s' and field2 = '%s'", a, a)`.  The alternative is to sanitize your args `safe_a = MySQLdb.escape_string(a)` and then use `format()` but that just seems verbose to me.

Comment: ok thanks but that doesnt answer the question of how to represent repeating parameters i.e instead of giving 'a' twice in the parameter list.

Comment: If you really want to use `format()` and not repeat your args `format()` can take a number that denotes the position of the argument: `cur.execute("select * from TableA where field1 = '{0}' and field2 = '{0}'".format(MySQLdb.escape_string(a)))`

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I wanted.

Comment: Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a number inside the brackets to refer to positional arguments.

```
safe_a = MySQLdb.escape_string(a) # protect against sql-injection!!!
cur.execute("select * from TableA where field1 = '{0}' and field2 = '{0}'".format(safe_a))
```

Comment: I use this way commonly too and I think is the most easy and readable way todo do this.